# Ssis deployment

Tags: json, git, ssis, tokenize

how to handle project parameter in git release.

Details: I am using json as configuration.  Deploying Ispac and json on ssis catalog version 2016.

How should I tokanize variable value for project parameter

Comment: I got the answer. We can use same way which is used for package level parameters.

Comment: You have to write this as answer